# Return statements in python

Tags: python, return

Just a quick one guys and gals, it's about return statements inside user defined functions.
This might be me just being a bit simple but here goes:-

In this example he returns 5 and then later sets the number variable to = give_me_five. So now I'm thinking that all return statements should belong to the functions initial name.

```
def give_me_five():
    five = 5
    return five

# main
display("Here's a message for you.\n")

number = give_me_five()
print("Here's what I got from give_me_five():", number)
```

so far so good right? Well hold on to your pants.

```
EMPTY = " "

def new_board():
    """Create new game board."""
    board = []
    for square in range(NUM_SQUARES):
        board.append(EMPTY)
    return board
```

In the code above he creates a new list called board and fills it with spaces - " ". Then he returns the board so now new_board is = board.

But in the next user defined function he just calls the return name board?!

```
def display_board(board):
    """Display game board on screen."""
    print("\n\t", board[0], "|", board[1], "|", board[2])
    print("\t", "---------")
    print("\t", board[3], "|", board[4], "|", board[5])
    print("\t", "---------")
    print("\t", board[6], "|", board[7], "|", board[8], "\n")
```

He also tells us that functions can't see inside one another so how has he extracted board from new_board?

Sorry about this lengthy post but any help would be appreciated (didn't turn out to be that quick after all).

Thanks

Comment: You're missing the part where the code does `some_var = new_board(); display_board(some_var);`.

Comment: Ahhhhh right thank you, I've got it now. It turns out it was me being simple. Sorry everyone

Comment: Scope or scoping are the terms used to describe the behavior you are seeing.  Search for terms like 'Python scoping' to learn more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think some of the confusion arises from a lack of knowledge about parameters.  If you look at `display_board(board)`, the `board` inside the parentheses is a variable.  Within `display_board(board)` he's looking at the contents of the provided `board`, not the one defined in `new_board`.

To help understand it, he could just as easily define `display_board` like thus:

```
def display_board(variable):
    """Display game board on screen."""
    print("\n\t", variable[0], "|", variable[1], "|", variable[2])
    print("\t", "---------")
    print("\t", variable[3], "|", variable[4], "|", variable[5])
    print("\t", "---------")
    print("\t", variable[6], "|", variable[7], "|", variable[8], "\n")
```

As long as he calls `display_board` with the value he gets from `new_board` like so...

```
b = new_board()
display_board(b)
```

It doesn't matter what the name of `board` (or `variable`) is within `display_board`

Comment: I've just seen that in the "main" function he does exactly that as you just described pretty much. Cheers for the response. I'll green tick it when the 15 minutes are up.

Comment: Glad to help.  Do parameters make sense now?